# Optimize the phonejs mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, css, phonejs

I am currently working on LOB application for mobile. And using phonejs as base framework. As a start I am following sample application and guide line, and putting everything in different HTML, JS and CSS.

But while testing on Android phone, start up of application is little slow. So, I was wondering if I compressed and minify js and css, it will improve the performance?

Means I don't mind adding grunt or glup if it will help. Again I am not sure, how Phonejs is working internally. So, any kind of suggestion is welcome.

Let me know if any further details is required.

Comment: I dont hink `minification` will improve processing performance. The main agenda with that is to improve network latency. You should get help of performance monitoring using Chrome Dev Tools and pinpoint your specific issues.

Comment: i don't think u can , its network performance issue i guess

Comment: @sabithpocker in chrome it is working great. It is just taking little time while launching in Android.